# Jmeter beanshell post Processor double values update

Tags: jmeter, double, beanshell

Into a Beanshell PostProcessor
I have to increase a variable ( latitude_new) declared previously
I wrote following code

Please, could you help me to solve it?
I accept also other solutions belong JMeter World
Thank you so much

```
double example = Double.parseDouble(vars.get("latitude"));
double increment = 0.001;
double sum = example+increment;
vars.put("latitude_new",sum);
```

Into log viewer I get following error :

> 2023-01-16 10:07:26,757 ERROR o.a.j.u.BeanShellInterpreter: Error
> invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``
> double example = Double.parseDouble(vars.get("latitude")); double
> increment . . . '' :

Error in method invocation:

> Method put( java.lang.String, double ) not found in
> class'org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterVariables' 2023-01-16
> 10:07:26,758 WARN o.a.j.e.BeanShellPostProcessor: Problem in BeanShell
> script: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException:

Error invoking bsh method:

> eval  Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``     double example =
> Double.parseDouble(vars.get("latitude")); double increment . . . '' :

Error in method invocation:

> Method put( java.lang.String, double ) not found in
> class'org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterVariables'your text

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use [`vars.put()`](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#put(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)) function providing a Double as an argument, the options are in:

1. Either convert the Double to the String first
2. Or consider using [`vars.putObject()`](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#putObject(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object)) function which takes an [Object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) hence you can store literally anything there

Also be informed that [starting from JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) because [Groovy performance is much better comparing to user scripting engines](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-jmeter) so consider migrating.